# Code changes data types for no apparent reason?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been working with a particular set of data so far that has both object, float and int types. I noticed halfway through my work that suddenly all of the data types had been converted to objects.

I went through my code running `crx_data.dtypes` after each line of code and found that they seem to all change to object after this line:

```
crx_data[(crx_data["A7"] != "v") & (crx_data["A7"] != "h")] = "Other"
```

Is someone able to explain to me why this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think here missing column for replace with selecting by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

In your solution all columns are replaced to strings, so dtypes of all columns are changed to object.

```
crx_data.loc[(crx_data["A7"] != "v") & (crx_data["A7"] != "h"), 'A7'] = "Other"
```

Another solution:

```
crx_data.loc[~crx_data["A7"].isin(["v", 'h']), 'A7'] = "Other"
```

Comment: Thank you! But both of the options here seem to give me this `'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: @Jaimee-leeLincoln - oops, I forget for `loc`

Comment: Oh perfect, that's solved it! Thank you for the explanation as to why my original code didn't work as well!